# How to update earliest date on typeorm

Tags: javascript, node.js, date, typeorm

```
col  date
a    2021-07-26 00:00:00
a    2021-07-27 00:00:00
c    2021-07-26 00:00:00
d    2021-07-27 00:00:00
```

```
await getRepository(PricingPattern)
  .createQueryBuilder()
  .update({date:'2022-09-30'})
  .where({col:'a',date:// some logic which return earliest date})
  .execute()
```

it returned as follows.

```
col  date
a    2021-09-30 00:00:00
a    2021-09-30 00:00:00
c    2021-07-26 00:00:00
d    2021-07-27 00:00:00
```

but my desired result is as follows

```
col  date
a    2021-07-26 00:00:00
a    2021-09-30 00:00:00
c    2021-07-26 00:00:00
d    2021-07-27 00:00:00
```

How can I extract the earliest date and update them in typeorm?

If someone has an opinion, will you please let me know?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use two queries to get the value of `col` and `date` of the row with minimum `date` value and then subsequently update the row using values found.

```
const data = await getRepository(PricingPattern)
  .createQueryBuilder()
  .select("col", "col")
  .addSelect("date", "date")
  .where("col = 'a'")
  .orderBy("date", "ASC")
  .limit(1)
  .getRawOne();

await getRepository(PricingPattern)
  .createQueryBuilder()
  .update({date: '2022-09-30'})
  .where({ col: data.col, date: col.date })
  .execute();
```

Or if you want to use a single query instead, you might use subquery like this:

```
const query = await getRepository(PricingPattern)
  .createQueryBuilder()
  .select("date")
  .where("col = 'a'")
  .orderBy("date", "ASC")
  .limit(1);

await getRepository(PricingPattern)
  .createQueryBuilder()
  .update({date: '2022-09-30'})
  .where({ col: 'a' })
  .andWhere("date IN (:date)", { date: query.getQuery() })
  .execute();
```